# Sturm-Liouville eigenfunctions in a double Robin condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, sturm-liouville

I'm solving a PDE by using the method of separation of variables, and this led me to a Sturm-Liouville of the form
$$
\dfrac{d^2f}{dx^2} + \lambda f = 0 \\[15pt]
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\dfrac{df}{dx}(0) - \alpha f(0) = 0 \\[5pt]
\dfrac{df}{dx}(\pi) + \alpha f(\pi) = 0
\end{array}\right.\ ,\quad \alpha > 0
$$

If I study the case where $\lambda = 0$ and where $\lambda < 0$, both of them results in $f$ being trivial, so no interest here. However, if $\lambda > 0$ then I get that infinite $\lambda_n$ exists (though, they are difficult to calculate exactly) such that $f$ is not trivial, and then I get a set of solutions with elements
$$
f_n(x) = A_n\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x) + B_n\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x)\ .
$$

My question: how can I apply the orthogonality property of eigenfunctions to express some initial condition as a generalized Fourier series?

I know that if $\phi_n$ and $\phi_m$ are the eigenfunctions related to eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ and $\lambda_m$, with $n \neq m$, then
$$
\int_0^\pi \phi_n(x)\phi_m(x)\ dx = 0\ ,
$$
which usually allow us to get an expression for the coefficients of the Fourier series. However, I don't know if the eigenfunctions are the sines and cosines separately, or the $f_n$ combination itself. If I take them separately, then I guess that
$$
\int_0^\pi \cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_m}x)\ dx = 0\ ,\quad\forall n,m
$$
but what about
$$
\int_0^\pi \cos(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x)\cos(\sqrt{\lambda_m}x)\ dx
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\pi \sin(\sqrt{\lambda_n}x)\sin(\sqrt{\lambda_m}x)\ dx\ ,
$$
which probably lead to different values if $n = m$ or $n \neq m$. I don't know how to correctly get a Fourier series from this if I don't have an explicit expression for $\lambda_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a solution $f$ of $f''+\lambda f=0$ with
$$
   f'(0)-\alpha f(0) = 0 \\
    f'(0)+\alpha f(0) = 1.
$$
The second condition is permitted without loss of generalization, just to provide normalization. This amounts to
$$
               f'(0) = 1/2,\;\; f(0)=1/2\alpha.
$$
This determines a solution of the form
$$
        f_{\lambda}(x) = A\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+B\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x) \\
             A=1/2\alpha,\;\; B\sqrt{\lambda}=1/2 \\
     \implies f_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{1}{2\alpha}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}x)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x).
$$
Notice that $f_{\lambda}(x)$ is an entire function of $\lambda$ with a limiting value of $\frac{1}{2\alpha}+\frac{x}{2}$ at $\lambda=0$, which is the correct solution for the problem where $\lambda=0$. The second condition $f'(0)+\alpha f(0)=1$ determines the eigenvalues to be the zeros of the entire function of $\lambda$ given by
$$
 0 = f_{\lambda}'(\pi)+\alpha f_{\lambda}(\pi)= \\
  = -\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{2\alpha}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)+\frac{1}{2}\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)+\frac{\alpha}{2\sqrt{\lambda}}\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) \\
  = \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{\sqrt{\lambda}}{\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\lambda}})\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)+\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi) \\
  =\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\frac{\lambda}{\alpha})\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}+\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi).
$$
There are solutions $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < \lambda_3 < \cdots$, and it is the eigenfunctions $\{ f_{\lambda_n} \}$ that are mutually orthogonal, not the component functions $\cos$ and $\sin$. These eigenfunctions $\{ f_{\lambda_n} \}$ can be used to expand a function in a series:
$$
                  f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\langle f,f_{\lambda_n}\rangle}{\langle f_{\lambda_n},f_{\lambda_n}\rangle} f_{\lambda_n}.
$$

Comment: [I got 2 formulations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3620739/276986) of the $L^2[0,\infty)$ Laplace transform problem but couldn't conclude