# How to prove Laplace transform is bounded on $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, laplace-transform, harmonic-analysis

The Laplace transform is defined by
\begin{equation}
(\mathscr{L}f)(s) \triangleq  
\int_0^\infty e^{-sx} f(x) dx, \quad s>0,
\end{equation}
then how can we check that the Laplace transform $\mathscr{L}$ is bounded as an operator from $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ to $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+)$ with norm $\sqrt{\pi}$?

Comment: Assuming $f$ is continuous and compactly supported and $\ge 0$ we get
$\int_0^\infty |\mathcal{L}f(y)|^2dy=\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-xy}dx\int_0^\infty f(z)e^{-zy}dz dy =\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty  \frac{f(x)f(z)}{x+z} dxdz $


$\asymp \int_0^\infty \int_0^x \frac{f(x)f(z)}{x} dxdz =\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)F(x)}{x}dx=\frac12 \int_0^\infty \frac{F(t)^2}{ t^2}dt$
where $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x)dx$ and $\asymp$ means bounded above and below up to a constant.

Comment: @reuns What if $f$ is not necessarily positive for all $x \geq 0$ and is only assumed to  be bounded and integrable? I am interested in controlling $\|f\|^2_{L^2}$ by some weighted $L^2$ norm of its Laplace transform, say for instance $\int_0^\infty \frac{|\mathcal{L}(\xi)|^2}{\xi} d\xi$ or $\int_0^\infty\frac{|\mathcal{L}(\xi)|^2}{\xi^2} d\xi$. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\|\mathscr{L}(f)\|_{L^2(0, \infty)}^2 =&\ \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0\int^\infty_0 dsdxdy\ e^{-s(x+y)}f(x)f(y)\\
=&\ \int^\infty_0 \int^\infty_0 dxdy\ \frac{f(x)f(y)}{x+y} = \pi\int^\infty_0 dx\ f(x) H(x)
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
H(f\chi_{[0, \infty)})(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty} dy\ \frac{f(y)\chi_{[0, \infty)}(y)}{x+y} =\frac{1}{\pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty} dy\ \frac{g(y)}{x+y}
\end{align}
defined for all $x>0$ is the Hilbert transform of $g=f\chi_{[0, \infty)}$.
Then it follows
\begin{align}
\|\mathscr{L}(f)\|_{L^2(0, \infty)}^2 \leq \pi\,\|f\|_{L^2(0, \infty)}\|H(g)\|_{L^2(0, \infty)}.
\end{align}
Using the $L^2-L^2$ boundedness of the Hilbert transform, we have the estimate
\begin{align}
\|\mathscr{L}(f)\|_{L^2(0, \infty)}^2 \leq \pi\, \|f\|_{L^2(0, \infty)}^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I was also looking for  answer to this question and your answer is really nice. But I am not able to understand the 2nd last line: " Using L^2-L^2 boundedness of Hilbert Transform". Can you please explain what this property is or give a reference to it?

Comment: @3ibfwcbi See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform#Boundedness

Comment: Where did you arrive at the estimate with the factor of $\pi$?  In the link you referenced, the tightest bound for the $L^2$ norm has a factor of $1$.  While $1<\pi$, what was the reason for your using an arbitrarily crude bound?

Comment: @MarkViola Did you look at the definition of the Hilbert transform?

Comment: Hi Jacky.  Yes I know the definition.  And I see now that your "$H\{\cdot\}$" is not the HT, it is $\pi$ times the Hilbert Transform.  May I suggest your considering using a notation different from $H$, conventionally used to represent the Hilbert Transform, especially in light of your reference to the HT.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks for the suggestion. To make the presentation be consistent with the Wikipedia reference, I have changed the definition of $H$ in my post to be the usual Hilbert transform definition.